# How can I auto refresh an HTML page that has an error?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, refresh

I have a weird problem.
I have a php script that runs only on our webserver and it processes a great deal of data as soon as a new processing job is put in the database.
Processing takes around 1-5 minutes.

What I did is run a php script that checks if there's an unfinished job in the database, and this page refreshes every 5 seconds by using the following html header:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

The server just runs this script so it gets picked up automatically.
The problem is: sometimes, when the server is busy, it throws an internal error 500. It means that the page stopped loading and will no longer refresh (even though a few seconds later it will be available again).

How can I best solve this problem?
I've considered letting Ajax do it with their polling system, the problem is that a processing job takes several minutes, and if there happen to be several processing jobs at the same time, it will start doing them all at the same time, which we don't want. And I don't even know if loading the page will stop when Ajax starts to refresh again, and thus not finishing the script.

If there are alternatives to run a PHP script when a new job is created in the database, I'd love to know as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your script using `cron`. Don't run it through a web browser. Don't even run it through a web server.

Comment: Oh right, forgot to say: this is a windows webserver that does the processing (because it uses Win32 executables for processing, so I'm using IIS on the processing server, which doesn't have cron, but just the windows task scheduler)

Comment: Then use Windows Task Scheduler, or install Cron (or move to a UNIX-like).

Comment: You put me really on the right track in finding my answer.
What I did was create a batch file in an endless loop that calls php to run the page itself, if the page fails, it will repeat itself again after the interval has passed. I'll put this into the task scheduler and it works!